# how to auto redirect to another page on basis of condition in razor?

Tags: razor

I am working to MVC3 and i want to check the condition and id condition is true then automatically redirect to another page in Razor. Kindly help me about how to auto redirect to anther page?

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    if (@Session["username"]==null)
    {
        //redirection code to page signInEmployee
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@{ Response.Redirect("~/HOME/NoResults");}

Answer (score -1):

This is controller logic, use `RedirectToAction` in action, but also you can use `section` in `header` with:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

OR (javascript)

```
document.location = 'url';
```